# Why do I get completely black labels when converting slices of nifty data to png images?

Tags: python, image-segmentation, unet-neural-network

I am quite new to deep learning and image segmentation tasks.

I want to train a 2D unet on 3D nifty data (CT scans) by taking the center 50 slices of every case. I saved the images and labels as png, but the labels are completely black. My goal is to predict the tumor region (Y), given a CT scan slice (X).

What am I doing wrong?

**My code:**

```
labels = []

for i in range (0,100):
  seg = Path("/content/drive/My Drive/")/"case_{:05d}".format(i) / "segmentation.nii.gz"
  seg = nib.load(seg)
  seg = seg.get_data()
  n_i, n_j, n_k = seg.shape
  seg = seg[int(((n_i-1)/2)-25):int(((n_i-1)/2)+25),:,:]

  for i in range(seg.shape[0]):
    labels.append((seg[i,:,:]))
    i+=1

labels = np.array(labels)

for i in range(labels.shape[0]):
    label = (labels[i,:,:])
    imsave('/content/drive/My Drive/labels/labels_slice_{:05d}.png'.format(i), label)
    i += 1
```

I do the same for the images ad get the following .png file:
[image_slice_00680](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82oki.png)

But for the labels I only get a completely black image.

Data type of image and label is float64 and uint16 respectively.

[Example segmentation nifti file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J9YcrxxZSqfBRdIWfDIcIxU1rdLgtOgS/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: What do you get when you print out `seg.max()` after you load the nifti file? Also, `.get_data()` seems to be deprecated and nipy now uses `.get_fdata()`. Can you upload an example nifti file to reproduce the error?

Comment: @jwitos Thank you for your comment. Printing `seg.max()` gives `2.0`. And [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J9YcrxxZSqfBRdIWfDIcIxU1rdLgtOgS/view) you have an example.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your nifti file in both 3D Slicer and nipy and the file is perfectly fine. Out of 608 slices in this segmentation file, only slices 181-397 have positive values, so you are supposed to get completely black images for the rest.

This short snippet allows me to save the positive example at the 300th slice:

```python
import nibabel
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

seg = nibabel.load("D:/Downloads/segmentation.nii.gz")
data = seg.get_fdata()
layer = data[300,:,:]

plt.imsave("D:/Downloads/seg.png", layer, cmap='gray')
```

[image]

Let me know if you can replicate this using the code above?

Also, I know it was not a part of the question, but you should strongly consider staying with nifti (or NRRD) format instead of converting them to PNG files.

1) When you are saving to PNG, you lose a lot of information from the CT scan. Basically you're rescaling CT values that often range from -2000 to +2000 to 0-255 pixel range.

2) Similarly with segmentation masks, in your nifti files segmented region is saved as "1" and background as "0". When you save it to PNG, you will get it rescaled to 0-255 and you will have to convert it back again for network training.

Comment: Thank you. I am able to replicate the result.

I understand what you mean, and processed the masks with the following code:
`masks = []

for i in range (0,25):
  b=[]
  msk = Path("/content/drive/My Drive")/"case_{:05d}".format(i) / "segmentation.nii.gz"
  b = nib.load(msk)
  b=b.get_fdata()
  print("mask case_{:05d}".format(i))
  b=resize(b,(b.shape[0],128,128))
  b=b[:,:,:]
  for j in range(b.shape[0]):
    masks.append((b[j,:,:]))

masks=np.asarray(masks)`

Would you say this is a good method or suggest something else?

Comment: Hi, it depends what are you ultimately trying to achieve. The code you posted in your last comment is a little bit confusing because it seems like `b` and `masks` matrices are the same. Also, I would double check how does `b` matrix looks after you resize it. Depending on which library you used (skimage? numpy?) it can change values of your original matrix.

Comment: If you'd like to continue this conversation via email you can reach me at jwitos at gmail.com.